# Capitalizing a word in Rails' view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capitalize

I'd like to know how to capitalize a word in a view. Example:

```
<% @employees.each do |employee| %>
  <%= employee.surname.capitalize %>
<% end %>
```

In my schema.db column surname is a string. So, why capitalization doesn't work? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Should work. Can you post the context of your view?

Comment: You should also post what you think the output of `capitalize` should be as well as what you're actually seeing. Maybe that method isn't what you really want.

Comment: For example, I have a surname smith in my db, and I want it to be Smith in the view.

Comment: `<%= employee.surname.capitalize %>` are you getting any error while doing so ? `capitalize` or `titleize` should work.

Comment: No errors at all. Just a surname like smith, not Smith. `capitalize`, `humanize`, or `titleize` doesn't work too.

Comment: Did you try to "something".capitalize and it outputs "Something"? If this works there is something wrong maybe reading or on upon saved your db.

Comment: When I put a string in a view like `<%= 'string'.capitalize %>` it gives me 'String', but I don't understand, why it doesn't work in `<%= employee.surname.capitalize %>`

Comment: Could you try to remove `.capitalize` and show us what `employee.surname` outputs?

Comment: `<%= employee.surname.mb_chars.capitalize %>` - can you try this ?

Comment: I have found what was wrong. In my db, the surname is cyrillic, that is why `capitalize` didn't work

Comment: Thanks, dkp. `<%= employee.surname.mb_chars.capitalize %>` works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `capitalize` for a string of special characters (non ASCII), then you can use [`mb_chars`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/mb_chars):

```
<%= employee.surname.mb_chars.capitalize %>
```